# Unable to locate package libopenmpi-dev on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, mpi

While trying to install open mpi on my Ubuntu 12.04, I am getting error `unable to locate package libopenmpi-dev`. What to do?

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev openmpi-bin openmpi-doc
unable to locate package libopenmpi-dev
unable to locate package openmpi-bin
unable to locate package openmpi-doc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to run `apt-get update` before you install the openmpi package.

Also you can use the following command to search all openmpi related package, for example:

```
apt-cache search openmpi
```

If it still doesn't work, try to use a different mirror, below is GUI and easier:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Update:

@Govind

The package is definitely in the official repository (12.04): http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libopenmpi-dev

As mentioned earlier, please run `apt-get update` and then `apt-cache search` for the libopenmpi packages.

If it still doesn't help. Try to change your mirror. Or paste the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Thanks Jokerdino for your suggestion but apt-cache search openmpi  not giving any result .Is that possible that libopenmpi is not available for Ubuntu 12.04 ?because it was working fine on my Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

I always run `apt-get update` and I was still getting the above error. The thing that did it for me was adding `--no-install-recommends` to the command.

For example:

`apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libopenmpi-dev`

Hope that helps someone in the future.

Comment: just `apt-get` returned me error `Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)` as I was not in root, `sudo` solved that.